# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() arguments dotnet and diff

Tags: c#, .net, diff

Trying to process a diff command gives me an error:

```
diff: extra operand `>'
```

Error is the same regardless of platform (under windows, I'm using choco diffutils).

```
var cmd = "diff" //if ran under windows is the choco path: C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\diff.exe
var args = "--unchanged-group-format='' --old-group-format='' --changed-group-format='%>' --new-group-format='' old.txt new.txt > diff.txt"
var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd, args)
p.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because > is not a part of the command arguments but the standard output redirection operand which is handled not by the process itself, but by the OS starting the process.

When starting a process through code, we need to handle this by ourselves.

Here is a solution working on windows:

```
var cmd = "diff"; //if ran under windows is the choco path: C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\diff.exe
var args = "--unchanged-group-format=\"\" --old-group-format=\"\" --changed-group-format=\"%>\" --new-group-format=\"\" old.txt new.txt";

var p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

p.Start();

using (var outputFile = File.OpenWrite("diff.txt"))
{
    p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(outputFile);
}

p.WaitForExit();
```

EDIT 1:

Having these two files (old.txt and new.txt)

```
   old.txt             new.txt
Line 1 - abc        Line 1 - def
Line 2 - def        Line 2 - def
Line 1 - abc        Line 1 - def
Line 2 - def        Line 2 - def
```

The output (diff.txt) is as follows:

```
Line 1 - def
Line 1 - def
Line 1 - def
Line 1 - def
```

Comment: Thank you @oguz, your solution works perfect! What's even more important, is that you explained the root of the issue, therefore this applies to any workflow involving standard output.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also accept as solution if you want. There is one more alternative which I see people use, and that is starting a shell (cmd.exe) and feed its standard input with the command line including both the executable and it's arguments (and then you can pass > diff.txt as well). I don't know if it's worth though, since we have this solutin.

Comment: I tried the alternative, and also works well! 

I'm sticking to the first solution, because the code looks more fluent that way. Thanks again.

Comment: I spoke too soon about "working perfect". I definitely works in terms of it outputting a file, but something strange is happening, and I'm trying to figure out if it's related particularly to diff.exe. string o = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); wraps the entire output in eight single quotes (4 at the begining and 4 at the end), looking like this: ''''<output text>''''. Please let me know if you're aware of anything like it. Again, this seems to be something completely unrelated, but I wanted to run it by you first.

Comment: Let me see how it behaves, I did not see this when I run it.

Comment: Ok I just tried again and it does not do that, I created the files myself (dummy text files for comparison), adding them to my answer

Comment: What happens when you run it manually from the command line? Does the output file has any single quotes?

Comment: No, when ran in the cmd or terminal, the file it has no single quotes. Also, it must be the diff format argument, because when I run it without any extra arguments, the output is correct.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue with my code... the documentation for diff (line group formats) shows single quotes wrapping eg; '%<', that caused the output wrapping in my code... I changed my code to your example which uses double quotes "%<". That did it!