# C# Starting process with args in specific folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to decompile over 30k vulkan shader files using shaderc from google.
All shaders are located in "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NMS MOD\SHADER MOD\v2.41\PC"

The tool used to decompile is spirv-cross.exe which I added to Windows Environment variables, which lets me run this simple bat file inside the shaders folder and works fine.
"spirv-cross --version 450 --vulkan-semantics --stage frag ATMOSPHERE_FRAG_CLOUD_769.SPV > ATMOSPHERE_FRAG_CLOUD_769.GLSL"

Since there is way too many to do this manually. I want to make a simple App to do this process and also get the stage type from file name (in this case "frag").

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Lazy_Me_3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string PATH;
        public string[] sFilesNames;
        public int totalcount = 0;
        public int currentcount = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string GetStageType(string filename)
        {
            // Valid Stages = vertex, vert, fragment, frag, tesscontrol, tesc, tesseval, tese, geometry, geom, compute, comp

            if (filename.Contains("_VERTEX_") || filename.Contains("_VERT_")) return "vert";
            if (filename.Contains("_FRAGMENT_") || filename.Contains("_FRAG_")) return "frag";
            if (filename.Contains("_TESSCONTROL_") || filename.Contains("_TESC_")) return "tesc";
            if (filename.Contains("_TESSEVEL_") || filename.Contains("_TESE_")) return "tese";
            if (filename.Contains("_GEOMETRY_") || filename.Contains("_GEOM_")) return "geom";
            if (filename.Contains("_COMPUTE_") || filename.Contains("_COMP_")) return "comp";

            else return "error";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sFilesNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                sFilesNames[i] = Path.GetFileName(sFilesNames[i]);

                if (sFilesNames[i].Length > 1)
                {
                    var newName = sFilesNames[i].Substring(0, sFilesNames[i].Length - 4);
                    sFilesNames[i] = newName;
                }
            }

            foreach (var file in sFilesNames)
            {
                string stageType = GetStageType(file);
                if (stageType != "error")
                {
                    string args = "--version 450 --vulkan-semantics --stage " + stageType + " " + file + ".SPV" + " > " + file + ".GLSL";

                    Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = "spirv-cross";
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = PATH;
                    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    process.Start();

                    process.WaitForExit(5000);

                    currentcount += 1;
                    label1.Text = "Status : " + currentcount.ToString() + " / " + totalcount.ToString();
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Error on finding stage type of file : " + file);
            }
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
                {
                    sFilesNames = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.SPV");
                    totalcount = sFilesNames.Length;

                    PATH = fbd.SelectedPath;
                    label3.Text = "Directory : " + PATH;
                    label2.Text = "Total Count : " + totalcount.ToString();
                    label1.Text = "Status : 0 / " + totalcount.ToString();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1 : Bodge using cmd that works

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sFilesNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                //sFilesNames[i] = Path.GetFileName(sFilesNames[i]);

                if (sFilesNames[i].Length > 1)
                {
                    var newName = sFilesNames[i].Substring(0, sFilesNames[i].Length - 4);
                    sFilesNames[i] = newName;
                }
            }

            foreach (var file in sFilesNames)
            {
                string stageType = GetStageType(file);
                if (stageType != "error")
                {
                    var p = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/c spirv-cross --version 450 --vulkan-semantics --stage " + stageType + " " + file + ".SPV" + " > " + file + ".GLSL");

                    p.UseShellExecute = false;
                    p.CreateNoWindow = true;

                    var ps = Process.Start(p);

                    ps.WaitForExit();

                    currentcount += 1;
                    label1.Text = "Status : " + currentcount.ToString() + " / " + totalcount.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    errorcount += 1;
                    label4.Text = "Errors : " + errorcount.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to full path of the exe in following statement : process.StartInfo.FileName = "spirv-cross";

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, even with full path, same problem. When debugging _spirv-cross_, does indeed run, but I'm guessing either the **args** are not working or the **WorkingDirectory** (maybe).
The doubt on working directory is because I replaced _spirv-cross_ with _cmd_ and captured output and cmd was running from the specified working directory.
Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: `>` is shell redirection. You cant use it via `Process`. Instead you need to capture the StandardOutput from the process and write it to a file yourself.

Comment: You must have the full path for the executable.  You can do it with Process class.  I've been doing things like this since DOS PCs (no different).  The file names like ATMOSPHERE_FRAG_CLOUD_769.GLSL also need the full path.  The ">" file will also need full path.  If you do not include the > in the command line then you can capture with StandardOutput.

Comment: Check a very similar problem and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296870/system-diagnostics-process-start-arguments-dotnet-and-diff/61297448#61297448

Comment: If you want the Process to create the output file automatically then you need to >.  The link Oguz provided is when the app needed the data and used standard output.  You do not need to use standard output if you specify the full path of where you want to create the output file.  A c# application assumes the program is working from same folder as where the exe file is located.  There is no path environmental variable.  Any input/output files that are not in the same folder as the exe must contain a path to the files (either relative or full path name).